# SQL Server 2012 intellisense

Tags: sql-server, intellisense

Why sometimes i have to wait for the intellisense reaction, which never comes and
sometimes the intellisense works fine and fast?

Bad connection to the server or some configuration problem?

Comment: Any news on this as intellisense is not working for me either...

Answer (score 8):

It caches intellisense information (which is why you sometimes need to refresh manually). When this needs to be refreshed/retrieved, it takes a short time; afterwards it just uses cached information which is available right away.

So if you have the impression that the intellisense doesn't work (e.g. no popup, or missing or outdated information), just refresh it: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (Edit -> Intellisense -> Refresh Local Cache).

It's also important to remember that only 2008 onwards supports Intellisense; if you connect to a pre-2008 database with the new SSMS you still won't get Intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it seems like Microsoft broke it again.  It doesn't work for me either.  I tried all the steps from [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2591/troubleshooting-intellisense-in-sql-server-management-studio-2012/) but without luck.

This document also has the link to [feedback site](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/717063/ssms-intellisense-does-not-function-for-a-contained-user) but it seems like Microsoft is not even bother about fixing this bug.

Sorry couldn't help much...

Answer (score 0):

I got this solution in a thread on MSDN site while finding the solution for same issue.

I removed the extension in Visual Studio 2010, and uninstalled SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) 2010, restarted, and intellisense works fine now.

I'm not sure if that helps since I don't know if you have SSDT installed, but I thought I'd share anyway.

Cheers,

Abhishek